# How many values of $\alpha$ are in interval $[0,2\pi)$ such that $\alpha=\left(12\left(12\alpha\bmod 2\pi\right)\bmod 2\pi\right)$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> How many values of $\alpha$ are in interval $[0,2\pi)$ such that
>   $$\alpha=\left(12\left(12\alpha\bmod 2\pi\right)\bmod 2\pi\right)$$

I first tried to split problem into cases:
There are $12$ different cases, so first case $\alpha\in\left(0,\frac\pi6\right)$, then
$$\alpha=(144\alpha \bmod 2\pi)$$
but again I need to split it into cases. Is there an easy way to just count solutions without saces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to split it into cases.  If add $2k \pi$ to the inner term, it gets multiplied by $12$ to make $24 k \pi$ and the outer $\pmod {2\pi}$ takes care of it.  So you have $\alpha =144 \alpha \pmod {2 \pi}$ or $143 \alpha = 2k \pi$  You get one solution for each $k$ in $[0,143)$, or $143$ of them.